# iOS - UITableViewCell, set subView background image when highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview

I define the UITableViewCell (and subview) as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init]; // Without this, subviews stack on one another

    ... cell stuff (textLabel, etc)

    UIButton *buttonDown = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [buttonDown setFrame:CGRectMake(190.0, 7.0, 40.0, 30.0)];
    [buttonDown setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonDown setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [buttonDown setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonDown.tag = indexPath.row;
    [buttonDown addTarget:self action:@selector(quantityDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:buttonDown];

    return cell;
}
```

The button initializes with the correct background color, and the button properly calls the method when I select it, but the background color does not change when selected.

I've tried placing it in the method call, as follows:

```
- (void) quantityDown:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

But still no dice.  Even a simple `[btn setBackGroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` won't do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1:**

So I was playing around with this, and the button background image *does* change, but only if you hold on the button (versus just a quick tap or click).

Even creating a custom cell has the same "must hold on button to change background" requirement.  Custom cell defined as follows:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

        [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        [self.downButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.downButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Since the custom cell has the exact same behavior as the original code, I'm trying to stick with the original.  Regardless, any thoughts on why the delay/need to hold down the button?  Why not instant, as is the case everywhere else I use the `setBackgroundImage:forState:` method?

Comment: Not setBackGroundColor, but setBackgroundColor. And, your image is png? If not, you should append extension to your name

Comment: Why don't you design a custom cell on storyboard? You can set all these thing on the properties panel.

Comment: Did you try the following: forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected) instead

Comment: @nicael sorry, that was a typo when creating the question, not how it appeared in the code.  Also, images are PNG and I have tried including the extension, but still no change.  I use these exact same images for UIButtons that appear in a regular viewController and they all work fine.  It's just these ones in the UITableViewCells that are giving me a headache.

Comment: @mdebeus I tried it and no luck.  I think I might have to try Marcal's approach and design the custom cell in storyboard.

Comment: Maybe replace (id)sender with (UIButton*)sender?

Comment: So what do you want the background color to be? It seems that you are changing the image - but I don't see you setting the background color anywhere.

Comment: @mdebeus the background color *is* the image.  I want the button background to change when the user presses it (only WHILE the user is pressing it), just so they know that the button is responding to their touch.  Setting the background color exclusively, I haven't been able to change the background color based on the state.  Using PNG images of solid colors, I can change the button appearance using `setBackgroundImage:forState:`

Comment: Just edited in some new information to the bottom of the original question, if any of you might have a solution/fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post about button highlight delay inside of a UIScrollView: [Is it possible to remove the delay of UIButton's highlighted state inside a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541159/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-delay-of-uibuttons-highlighted-state-inside-a-uisc)

A UITableView is a subclass of a UIScrollView.